# Lookahead assertions (regular expressions) not working in JFlex

Tags: java, regex, jflex

I am trying to generate a scanner using JFlex.

One of the identifier rules for the grammar I am trying to implement is as follows (in regex syntax):

```
[a-zA-Z]((_(?!_)|[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-zA-Z0-9])?
```

I have verified that the above expression is actually valid and works. However, it seems jFlex 1.4.3 does not like my use of the lookahead assertion `(?!_)` as it keeps complaining of the "*question mark*". Is there something I am doing wrong or is there a different to use lookaheads in JFlex?

I am using the "*lookahead*" to satisfy the rule that says I cannot have two consecutive underscores in the identifier name.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be rather easy to rewrite the regexp to allow a single underscore, followed by one or more characters within [a-zA-Z0-9] too (with the * after that).

Comment: @owlstead - Your comments came just seconds after my post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
[a-zA-Z]((_(?!_)|[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-zA-Z0-9])?
```

use **optimized** pattern

```
[a-zA-Z]+(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*
```

Comment: There are probably omega number of regexp for this ;)

Comment: @owlstead - Sure there are many options. My pattern uses `+` in each section of pattern to minimize number ot iterations to make it as fast as possible...

Comment: Should be faster than the original this way, so I won't go and try to improve it (kind of hard without using `?` anyway).